# Getting a value from function

Tags: php, function

I'm finishing a script that converts a string and pass it as a link, but besides that, it also shortens the URL with an API. The problem is that I can not think how to get only the URL instead of the entire chain.

The function:

```
function findAndShort($string) {
    $text = preg_replace("/(https?|ftps?|mailto):\/\/([-\w\p{L}\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\p{L}\/_\.#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/u", '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string);
    return $text; 
}
```

Example:

```
$chk = findAndShort("Blahblah http://domain.tld");
echo $chk;
```

In this case, only need the http://domain.tld, i try with $chk[0], but ofcourse, print the first character on the line..

Comment: By the url do you mean what's inside the href="..."?

Comment: *The problem is that I can not think how to get only the URL instead of the entire chain* What do you mean with that? What is a "chain"? Please elaborate and provide some sample input and output, and what you want to get as result. The clearer you describe your problem, the better answers you will get.

Comment: OK! I managed to extract and convert the url, using an old API (http://paste2.org/p/1814464).. but now the problem is, I can not convert all the links (I'm quite sure that the problem is in the regexp, in the paste2 link, line 99), for example: `http://localhost/index.php/topic,28410.0.html`, only extracts to `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `^.*` at the begining of your regex and use $1 instead of $0:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^.*((https?|ftps?|mailto):\/\/([-\w\p{L}\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\p{L}\/_\.#,]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/u", '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $string);
```

You can also simplified a bit,

```
~^.*((https?|ftps?|mailto)://[-\p{L}\p{N}_.]+(:\d+)?(/([\p{L}\p{N}/_.#,]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)~u
```

Comment: Now all the text is a link. I just need the link itself, ie capture the url of the string and turn it into a variable

Comment: @wiitohzjeh: useone more parentheses pair and use $1 instead of $0. See my edit.

Comment: @wiitohzjeh: just add a comma `,` in the character class. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with functions is you can only return a single value that is under the `return` in the function, so in your case, after testing your function, the return value is the original input value.

If you want a function to return only the URL component I would use `explode` to separate the string then run `preg_match` on each part of the resulting array from the `explode` function looking for the https, ftp or mailto, once I know what part of the array I'm working with I would stop the process, define the var and as I believe you want to return code for a link, I would do is then do something like

`return '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';`

Note that the var `$url` would be created from the above process.

I hope this helps.